# No setter method for assignment to property

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, setter, nsobject

I have my constants and custom enums in a separate .h file. The file is a subclass of `NSObject`.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnumName) {
    EnumValueOne,
    EnumValueTwo
};
```

In another class which is also a subclass of `NSObject`, I have a property for said enum.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) MyEnumName hello;
```

And inside its implementation file, I'm trying to set its value like so,

```
self.hello = EnumValueTwo;
```

But I get an error at that line saying,

**No setter method 'setHello:' for assignment to property**

I tried declaring a setter method manually for that property but it still didn't work.

If I do the same inside a view controller, it works fine. Cannot do that in the `NSObject` subclass.

Can someone tell me why this is and how to correct it?

Thank you.

Comment: please show the whole context where you are saying `self.hello`

Comment: There's actually nothing more than this. I'm just trying to set the value to that property in a method. The whole method body has only this line of code.

Comment: did you @synthesize hello? Need this with older versions of compiler

Comment: No, this is targeted for iOS 7 using Xcode 5. I synthasized it and still the problem is there.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, if it works in one file and not in another then there is some crucial difference between them. I can't reproduce the problem here - it works for me, just as it does in your view controller class. If you are not willing to show more context, I can't help you.

Comment: Vote to close on basis of insufficient info.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot post the original project but [here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpjc7dfso2hj469/EnumTest.zip) a demo project. Its weird because I have set up the classes and method exactly as the original one but in this, a different error is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the example project you try to call self in a class method.. this is you r problem not the enum. you can't access self or any instance variable from a class method.

Comment: Is there any other way to set a value to a property in a class method at all? Or is making the method an instance method the only option?

Comment: Properties are a means of providing access to instance variables. so if you don't have an instance you clearly don't have the instance's variables. depend of your needs you can maybe use a static variable, which you can access from instance or class methods.

Comment: @Isuru  And indeed this is exactly what I was guessing was the case when I asked for the context. That is precisely where I was going all this time. All you had to do was show me the actual method declaration. It's a good idea to cooperate with those trying to help you.

Comment: @Isuru Classes can have more than one instance (imagine if that weren't the case — you could only have one NSString in your entire program!). If you try to set a property in a class method, what instance's property should it set? So it isn't that the language is just forcing you to use an instance method. It's that it doesn't *mean* anything to set an instance variable without an instance.